# React Curly Brace Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Embarassing, but I cannot figure out how to write something fairly basic in React with JSX. I have looked online, and here as well, but nothing helped. I also took a look into the official React documents, but even when they are explaining basic things, it seems like an alien is explaining it to me.

I literally just want a basic j query function with all of its syntax to appear on the screen, but it keeps hiding one of my brackets.

```
$('#btn').click(function() your code here });
```

As you can see, it takes the other curly brace out. I am in no means attempting to execute any jQuery, this is supposed to show the function to explain how it works to someone.

Comment: Is it possible to have `<button id="btn" onclick="sampleFunction()">Start</button>`

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by this, I am not attempting to execute any code, or create any HTML elements, basically I was asking how to print a string to the screen that contains a jquery function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>{"$('#btn').click(function() { your code here });"}</div>`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/57108/)

or you can save it to a variable

```
var jQueryExample = "$('#btn').click(function() { your code here });"

render() { return <div>{jQueryExample}</div> }
```